# How to pass Tab in a command line argument in a Robot Framework test case?

Tags: robotframework

I query an SQL Server table from a Robot Framework test case via ssh and would like to have Tab as a separator in the query result, so I try to pass the option -s "<Tab>" to sqlcmd. In Robot Framework I have tried the following syntax:

```
|${result} =|run process|ssh|admin@${SRV_IP}|sqlcmd|-S|.\\\\SQLEXPRESS|-d|${DB_NAME}|-s|\t|-W|-Q|"select ..."|
```

but apparently the \t sequence is not expanded to a Tab character as in the log I see

```
10:47:32.411    INFO    Starting process: ['ssh', 'admin@192.168.77.129', 'sqlcmd', '-S', '.\\\\SQLEXPRESS', '-d', 'test_main', '-s', '\t', '-W', '-Q', '"select ...;"']
```

and after the execution of the command stderr contains

> Sqlcmd: '-s': Missing argument. Enter '-?' for help.

I have also tried to write \x09 instead of \t, but \t appears in the log anyway. What is the syntax for Tab such that it is expanded when it is passed as a command line argument to a process?

I assume I could do it by specifying shell=True and writing the whole command line in one string, but manually escaping characters one time for the Python syntax and twice for the shell syntax becomes hasslesome, so I wouldn't immediately go this way.

Comment: Have you tried adding extra `\`s? The backslash is removed by robot before the command line is run. Perhaps using `\\t` will work, as robot will convert `\\` to a single `\`, so that the shell will see `\t`. You might need more backslashes, I don't know what `run process` is doing under the covers.

Comment: You are 100% right, `\\\t` (three backslashes) is the answer to my question although I don't quite see why. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add more backslashes. The first backslash will be eaten up by Robot Framework long before sqlcmd ever sees it. You might need two backslashes, and you might need three or four. It depends on what else is doing substitutions before the command is finally executed. Since you have Robot Framework calling ssh which calls sqlcmd, you may need several.

While the number of backslashes is deterministic, experience has taught me that sometimes the easiest thing is to just keep adding more until it works.